# Assigning a <- b in a loop but a doesn't change as b changes

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, split

I'm new to R and I have this issue when loop.
I split a df then want to assign the `num` variable to a certain value depending on the function input. The problem is when `evaluate(num = 'low')` the value of `num` and `nrow[[i]]` are different. How does it happen?

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(cat = c(rep('a',3), rep('b',2),
                   rep('c',5)),
                 val = sample(1:100, 10))
s <- split(df, df$cat)
evaluate <- function(num) {
  for (i in 1:length(s)) {
    if (num == 'high') {
    num <-1
    } else if (num == 'low') {
    num <- nrow(s[[i]])
    } else {
    num <- num
    }
    print(num)
    print(nrow(s[[i]]))
  }
    s[[i]][num,]
}
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense. At `i=1`, num is changed from "low" to 3. At `i=2`, the condition `num=='low'` is no longer satisfied and therefore `num<-num` is evaluated.

Comment: It is not clear what result your actually attempting to achieve.  I.e. s is a list of 3 dataframes.  So you are attempting to modify each dataframe how?

Comment: @GregordeCillia omg now I've just realized how stupid this mistake is. Thank you for explaining this!

Comment: @SteveM I just want to give a simplified version of the problem that I encountered.